# How to improve the margin and padding of JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, padding, margin, grid-layout

When I initially run my Java Swing application, the padding and margining of the `JLabel` and `JTextField` components in a `JPanel` look good. But whenever I resize the application, the padding and margining for the labels and text fields increases so much that it does not look as good.

I understand a `GridLayout` has a set amount of vertical and horizontal spacing, but what can I do to make the spacing look better as the size of the application increases? I would also like the text in the text fields to resize as the text field increases but have been unable to figure it out.

I have been thinking to use a `GridBagLayout` but have not had much luck with that either. There is just way too much spacing as the size increases, which does not look good, and I have been unable to find or learn a good solution.

I would appreciate any advice.

### Code:

```
package TestPackage;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestGridLayout  {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
             JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(); 
             
             GridLayout layoutManager = new GridLayout(5,2); 
              testPanel.setLayout(layoutManager); 
             
             JLabel platformEnumerationNameLabel = new JLabel(); 
            JLabel logicalEnumerationNameFieldLabel = new JLabel(); 
            JLabel valueTypeUnitNameFieldLabel = new JLabel(); 
            JLabel measurementNameFieldLabel = new JLabel(); 
             JLabel measurementAxisNameFieldLabel = new JLabel(); 
            
             JTextField platformEnumerationNameField = new JTextField(); 
             JTextField logicalEnumerationNameField = new JTextField(); 
             JTextField valueTypeUnitNameField = new JTextField(); 
            JTextField measurementNameField = new JTextField(); 
            JTextField measurementAxisNameField = new JTextField(); 
            
            platformEnumerationNameLabel.setText("Label 1");   
            testPanel.add(platformEnumerationNameLabel); 
            
            platformEnumerationNameField.setText("input some data"); 
            testPanel.add(platformEnumerationNameField); 

            logicalEnumerationNameFieldLabel.setText("Label 2");
            testPanel.add(logicalEnumerationNameFieldLabel); 
            
            logicalEnumerationNameField.setText("input some data"); 
            testPanel.add(logicalEnumerationNameField); 
            
            valueTypeUnitNameFieldLabel.setText("Label 3");
            testPanel.add(valueTypeUnitNameFieldLabel);
            
            valueTypeUnitNameField.setText("input some data");
            testPanel.add(valueTypeUnitNameField); 
            
            measurementNameFieldLabel.setText("Label 4");
            testPanel.add(measurementNameFieldLabel);
            
            measurementNameField.setText("input some data");
            testPanel.add(measurementNameField); 
            
            measurementAxisNameFieldLabel.setText("Label 5");
            testPanel.add(measurementAxisNameFieldLabel);
            
            measurementAxisNameField.setText("input some data");
            testPanel.add(measurementAxisNameField);  
            
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
            
            dialog.add(testPanel);
            
            dialog.setSize(700,200); 
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use a `GridBagLayout`

Comment: Java Swing doesn't automatically rescale the font sizes.  Calculating the font sizes manually based on the main `JPanel` size would be difficult.  You could pick two or three font sizes and let the `JFrame` pack itself to the appropriate size, but that would require extra coding on your part.  Otherwise, @MadProgrammer's answer is the best you will be able to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different layout manager that doesn't resize all the components (unless you want them to)

[image: Packed][image: Resized]

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            JLabel platformEnumerationNameLabel = new JLabel();
            JLabel logicalEnumerationNameFieldLabel = new JLabel();
            JLabel valueTypeUnitNameFieldLabel = new JLabel();
            JLabel measurementNameFieldLabel = new JLabel();
            JLabel measurementAxisNameFieldLabel = new JLabel();

            JTextField platformEnumerationNameField = new JTextField(20);
            JTextField logicalEnumerationNameField = new JTextField(20);
            JTextField valueTypeUnitNameField = new JTextField(20);
            JTextField measurementNameField = new JTextField(20);
            JTextField measurementAxisNameField = new JTextField(20);


            platformEnumerationNameLabel.setText("Label 1");
            add(platformEnumerationNameLabel, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            platformEnumerationNameField.setText("input some data");
            add(platformEnumerationNameField, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            logicalEnumerationNameFieldLabel.setText("Label 2");
            add(logicalEnumerationNameFieldLabel, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            logicalEnumerationNameField.setText("input some data");
            add(logicalEnumerationNameField, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            valueTypeUnitNameFieldLabel.setText("Label 3");
            add(valueTypeUnitNameFieldLabel, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            valueTypeUnitNameField.setText("input some data");
            add(valueTypeUnitNameField, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            measurementNameFieldLabel.setText("Label 4");
            add(measurementNameFieldLabel, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            measurementNameField.setText("input some data");
            add(measurementNameField, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            measurementAxisNameFieldLabel.setText("Label 5");
            add(measurementAxisNameFieldLabel, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            measurementAxisNameField.setText("input some data");
            add(measurementAxisNameField, gbc);
        }

    }
}
```